# Make Column Array dynamic

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following code to run a sum formula at the bottom of specific columns based on a dynamic range of rows.  My limitation is that i have to define which columns i wan this to happen to.  How can i make it dynamic based on the last column with data in it?

Thanks

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Sum()

Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "Master" And WS.Name <> "How to" And WS.Name <> "Template" Then

     Dim CurCal As XlCalculation
     Dim wb As Workbook, colsLastRow As Long
     Dim cols As Variant, SumCols As Long, colsArray As Variant
     Dim biggestRow As Long
     Dim shNAMES As Range

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        CurCal = Application.Calculation
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        biggestRow = 1

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook

        colsArray = Array("L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ")

        For Each cols In colsArray
        colsLastRow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, cols).End(xlUp).Row
        If colsLastRow > biggestRow Then
        biggestRow = colsLastRow + 1
        End If
        Next cols

        For Each cols In colsArray
        colsLastRow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, cols).End(xlUp).Row
        WS.Cells(biggestRow, cols).Formula = "=SUM(" & cols & "9:" & cols & colsLastRow & ")"
        Next cols

        WS.Range("B" & biggestRow).Value = "TOTAL"

        WS.Cells(3, 3).Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(N:N<>""""),N:N)"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = CurCal
    End If
Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you give an example? Where in the above would you use the last column and do you expect colArray to hold all the columns up to and including this?

Comment: I have a a table that is columns B through (X amount of columns) with data on rows 9 through (X amount of rows).  I want a sum formula below the last row for columns L through (variable amount of columns) for all data in that column up to row 9.  The columns may end at z or they may end at AZ.  right now i have to define exactly which columns i want summed in the array.  I want that to change dynamically.

Comment: Is it an excel table? I.e. an actual table that if you were to put a formula in one column it would autofill down?

Comment: yes just data in excel. but i need to going across a row, not down a column

Comment: And you intend to sum from row 9 down?

Comment: 9 down to last row of data for each column, yes.

Comment: Updated code. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: there was an extra parenthesis on the last function i removed.  but it just brings up a box saying "how to"  doesn't have any columns past L.  so for some reason its checking the WS that i'm trying to exclude.  I also don't need a msg box as there will always be columns past L

Comment: Version 1 will warn you. Use version 2.

Comment: I assume C3 is going to be empty as you are adding a formula into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

Ignoring sheets where not enough rows or columns

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim CurCal As Variant
    CurCal = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long
    Const startRow As Long = 9                   '<=====change this to sum from a different row
    Const startColumn As Long = 12               '<====change this for column to start putting totals at
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            On Error Resume Next
            lastColumn = GetLastColumn(ws)
            lastRow = GetLastRow(ws)
            If .Name <> "Master" And .Name <> "How to" And .Name <> "Template" Then
                For i = 1 To lastColumn - startColumn + 1
                    .Cells(lastRow, i + startColumn - 1).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=Sum(" & .Range(.Cells(startRow, i + startColumn - 1), .Cells(lastRow, i + startColumn - 1)).Address & ")"
                Next i
                If ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count > startRow - 1 And ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count > startColumn - 1 Then
                    ws.Range("B" & lastRow + 1) = "TOTAL"
                    ws.Cells(3, 3).Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(N:N<>""""),N:N)"
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = CurCal
End Sub

Public Function GetLastColumn(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, ws.UsedRange) > 0 And ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column > 11 Then
        GetLastColumn = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Long
    If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, ws.UsedRange) = 0 And ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row > 8 Then
        GetLastRow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Version 2 does exactly what i need it to.  Thank you so much for the help.  You have no idea how much time you just saved me.

Comment: Just in case if i wanted to change which column it started.  What would i change?

Comment: Still new to all this.  So can i dim "a" as interger and link A to a cell which i can put in the number "11"  and then replace everywhere that currently says 11 as "a?

Comment: And yes you could use a cell in which case declare Dim startColumn As Long and point it at a cell.

Answer (score 0):

If your range is continuous you can find the first and last column like this:

Just adjust the `rng` range to fit your table data range

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim first_col_letter As String
Dim first_col_number As Long
Dim last_col_letter As String
Dim last_col_number As Long

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

    With rng

        first_col_letter = Chr(.Columns(1).Column + 64)
        first_col_number = .Columns(1).Column

        last_col_letter = Chr(.Columns(.Columns.Count).Column + 64)
        last_col_number = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I usualy use the ws.columns.count) .end(xltoleft/up).column to find last columns and last rows.  Is there a way to use that to put into the array so it would be something like colsArray = Array("L"-Lastcolumn)

Comment: Why not storing the columns numbers, If column "L" = column 12, `For i = 12 to LastColumn`?

Comment: How do i implement that?